# AJAX Fill Textbox Not Working

Tags: javascript, html

Here's my code, why won't it fill the input text box?

```
<html>
<head>
<script>
function textFill() {
document.getElementById("textbox").value("Test Here");
}
</script>
</head>
<body>
<input type="text" id="textbox" />
<button type="button" onclick="textFill()">Fill Text</button>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are doing it slightly wrong.

```
document.getElementById("textbox").value = "Test Here";
```

See this jsFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/9wTps/

Answer (score 2):

Try:

```
document.getElementById("textbox").value = "Test Here";
```

Comment: The web developer plugin for firefox might help you out in the future with bugs like this.